# How to run open dns on a network

Tags: networking

I need to be enlightened in this topic.

- First, is it possible to run open dns
  on a network so that you won't have
  to install the open dns updater to
  update the ip address of those
  machines with dynamic ip address.
- Second, how do I set it up. Can I set it up on the router?
- Third, would it be possible when using only an ordinary os. Not a server os. Just plain windows xp or windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you are running Windows Server 2003 for your network. You dont need the opens dns client. you need to to enable your DNS server to forward lookups to the open-dns servers ip address.

Go to your DNS management console. Right click on your server name. Go to properties. Select the forwarders Tab. and add the open-dns ip address to list of forwarders.

Comment: You need to setup custom dns server for your clients in DHCP server. Every type of dhcp servers has that configuration. but if you give more detail about your network topology. we can help more specific.